# jQuery validation plugin doesn't validate my form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

My main goal is check  the value that user enter in input, exists in database. So my validation looks like:

```
 $('#addForm').validate({ 
                rules: {
                    SendingName: {
                        required: true,

                        remote: {
                            url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Product.CheckUniqueSendingName())", 
                            type: "get",
                            data: {
                                subscriptionType: function () {
                                    return @Model.SubscriptionType;
                                },
                                 sendingName: function () {
                                     return $("#SendingName").val();
                                }
                                @*subscriptionType: @Model.SubscriptionType,  
                                sendingName: $("#SendingName").val()*@
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.Data) {
                                    $('#addForm').submit();
                                } else {
                                    message: {
                                        SendingName: 'Record  is already in use!'
                                    }
                                }

                            },
                            // for troubleshooting
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('status: ' + textStatus);
                                console.log('error: ' + errorThrown); 
                            },

                        }
                    }
                },
            });
```

My controller method:

```
public virtual JsonResult CheckUniqueSendingName(int subscriptionType, string sendingName)
        {
            var isUnique = _productService.CheckUniqueSendingName(ProductId, subscriptionType, sendingName);
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
            if (isUnique)
            {
                result.Data = false;
            }
            else
                result.Data = true;
            return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My field in form

```
<div class="form-group row">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SendingName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SendingName, new { @class = "form-control"})
                        <div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SendingName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So I need validate only one field in form. But when I submit form It doesn't validate my form, there are no errors. How can I archieve validation message error when submit my form? Thanks

UPDATE: generated html

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
<form action="product/addsendmailinglist" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="syd_kzSNc5Nl2H5_h4whYNwVgZcYVwxJ2TubrxE47yugkPbJYlj3DpgbUoGzypDLAknc0bNevWaMe65Miu73EAbwwMKEaXcyy5CqrGdsoXz4B7xExxp1CFyJ0YwOugUIry2k0xvhuvVN3Q3ZDi9nvA2" />            <div class="form-horizontal">

                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ProductId must be a number." data-val-required="The ProductId field is required." id="ProductId" name="ProductId" type="hidden" value="1095" />
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="EmailFrom">Email From</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Field is required" id="EmailFrom" name="EmailFrom" type="text" value="test@gmail.com" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="EmailFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="SendingName">Sending Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: SendingName" data-rule-sendingNameValidation="true" id="SendingName" name="SendingName" type="text" value="Fit-Zakaz" />
                        <div>
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SendingName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-9">
                        <input type="button" data-bind="click: submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded" />
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-rounded" href="/product/details?subscriptionType=2&amp;Tab=emailsending">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ASP includes the Unobtrusive Validation plugin... are you using it?  If so, then you cannot construct your own call to the `.validate()` method because it will just be ignored in favor of the version created by Unobtrusive.

Comment: @Sparky no I don't use Unobtrusive  validation here , hmm something strange , but with my existing code is there any solution?

Comment: You have to inspect your DOM and post the **RENDERED** HTML here so we can see why the JavaScript is not working.  The client-side code does not care about your Controller or View... only what's being sent to the browser.

Comment: @Sparky I update my question , sorry maybe I was not right about jQuery because there are data-val, data-val-required. I also try to use `addValidator` method but It isn't possible because I can't write there ajax request , It will not work. I also have `data-rule-sendingNameValidation` on SendingName field , but It is another rule which just check if field isn't empty

Comment: Makes no sense.  Code you posted should work.  Various common mistakes would generate JavaScript console errors.  Did you check your JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: @Sparky Yes sure , console is clear , I don't understand why it skips validation and submit form without any problem :/ maybe in success method I did the mistake

Comment: You have WAY TOO MUCH going on inside your `remote`.  Read the docs and look at others' examples here on SO.  The plugin takes the proper response from the server and ***automatically*** handles it.  You would NEVER need to put a `submit()` and error message inside of a `success` handler... that is the plugin's job already!

Answer (score 0):

okay guys , I try

```
 $(function () {
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("data-rule-checkunique", function (value) {

                var check_result = false;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Product.CheckUniqueSendingName())?subscriptionType=" +@Model.SubscriptionType + "&sendingName=" + $("#SendingName").val(),
                    async: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        subscriptionType: @Model.SubscriptionType,
                        sendingName: $("#SendingName").val()
                    }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (return_data) {
                        if (return_data.Data === false) {
                            check_result = false;
                        } else if (return_data.Data) {
                            check_result = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
                return check_result;
            }, "error message");
```

Important here it's async: false. I don't know if it is right way , but  apparently It works. I will listen your comments if I'm not right

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel. There is already a `[Remote]` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks i didn't know this attribute, I need read about it